# how to remove # from URL in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url-modification

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.
my project url is http://localhost/MyProject/app/#/index.html
I want to open index.html at url **http://localhost/MyProject/index.html**
How can i do this? can anyone help? thanks

```
angular.module('myapp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'homeController',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home_page.html'
    }) $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

if I use

```
<base href="index.html">
```

In the place of `<base href="/">`
then page half load with many insecure type error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in your config

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true
});
```

and then you have to set a  in the  of your document to use relative links.

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: i can't see anything with this.

Comment: could you provide us your js code ?

Comment: angular
 .module('myapp')
 .config([
 '$stateProvider',
 '$urlRouterProvider',
 '$httpProvider',
 '$locationProvider',
 function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) { 
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
  .state('index', {
   url: '/',
   controller: 'homeController',
   templateUrl: 'templates/home_page.html'
  })

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('*');

 }
 
 ]);

Comment: It wil be easier if you edit your first post with this code but i already see '.hashPrefix('*')' if you doesn't want '#' you shouldn't use this

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your angular.config :

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

and in index.html file :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

[More Info, check angular doc for $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)